# Focus textarea on ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to click a button from within `ng-repeat` and focus on `textarea` from that **specific item** in the loop.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <textarea focus-when="showTextarea">{{ item }}</textarea>
  <a ng-click="trigger()" href="#">Focus</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['World', 'Earth', 'Fire'];

  $scope.trigger = function() {
    $scope.showTextarea = true;
  }
});

app.directive('focusWhen', function($scope) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.focusWhen, function(value) {
        console.log(attrs);
        element.css('background','red');
        console.log(element[0]);
        element[0].focus();
      });      
    }
  }

});
```

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/By0hLs7U6CLbGD9ic9vO?p=preview

I have directive `focusWhen` which watched the `showTextarea` scope variable. When `ng-click` trigger, it will change this `showTextarea` to true and it should focus the `textarea`

However, my code doesn't work and it has error

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- focusWhenDirective`

I am not sure why. Two questions:

1. Can you help to point out where I got this wrong
2. How to do the focus after clicking?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I got this to work using code below

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="showForm=true; focusInput=true">show form and focus input #{{ item }}</button>
    <div ng-show="showForm">
      <input type="text" focus-me="focusInput">
      <button class="btn" ng-click="showForm=false">hide form</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
var MyCtrl = function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3];
};

app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: { trigger: '=focusMe' },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
        if(value === true) { 
          //console.log('trigger',value);
          //$timeout(function() {
            element[0].focus();
            scope.trigger = false;
          //});
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yZ21NYb5EkUTSAWOVjHZ?p=preview

I am not sure why but somehow using `scope: { trigger: '=focusMe' }` made a different. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
app.directive('focusWhen', function($scope) {
```

to

```
app.directive('focusWhen', function() {
```

Comment: Right, error on my part but I just splitted the questions out and still look for answer on `#2` above.